# Unable to Execute Java Class File

Tags: java

Getting an error for executing the java file with command `java ClassFileName` as below:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class.
```

but executing when using a command `java -cp . ClassFileName` without any error.

Can u please help me why it is happening. ?

Comment: Do you have a main in your class or a main class in your workspace?

Comment: yes, I have a main class in my class file.

Comment: show this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Comment: Related or even a suitable duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385353/why-do-i-have-to-use-java-cp-class-name-and-not-java-class-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must ensure that you add the location of your `.class` file to your classpath. 
So, if its in the current folder then add . to your classpath, which you've done and that's why it's working fine for you.

So, to execute using `java ClassFileName` just add the location of .class to your classpath. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Complile** a Java file to generate a class:

```
javac filename.java
```

**Execute** the generated class:

```
java filename
```